# Распарсить txt файл с временем в формате промежутка

Tags: java

Не получается распарсить txt файл с временем в формате промежутка "HH:MM - HH:MM" и записать значения в массив, где каждое начальное значение со знаком +, а конечное со знаком -. Считал файл BufferedReader, прошёлся по нему while, но как разделить значения строки на части и присвоить им значения не знаю. Уж извините за такую банальщину.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного не понятно куда надо добавлять знаки + и -, но прочитать файл, при условии что каждая запись с новой строки, и разбить строку вида "HH:MM - HH:MM" методом split() класса String. Вот пример:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("D:\\test.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        String string;

        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();

        while ((string = br.readLine()) != null){

            String[] parts = string.split(" - ");

            arr.add("+"+parts[0]);
            arr.add("-"+parts[1]);

        }

        for (String str : arr) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }

    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Ошибка");
    }
}
```

Comment: Каким то образом проиндексировать значения, что бы начальные были отдельно и конечные были тоже отдельно, но при этом лежали в одном массиве.

Comment: Нужен пример того как в файле хранятся ваши данные, и приведите пример массва который должен получиться в итоге... "что бы начальные были отдельно и конечные были тоже отдельно, но при этом лежали в одном массиве" тут сложно понять что вам требуется

Comment: 08:00 - 9:10
09:30 - 12:30         В столбец размещены промежутки времени. Надо найти все варианты их пересечения, что бы в дальнейшем посчитать, какое максимальное количество людей было на работе. Для этого мне предложили использовать массив где проиндексированы все значения ( + и -), что бы по максимальному значению, найти количество людей. Может быть есть и другие варианты.

Comment: Обновил ответ, привёл пример считывания файла построчно. Повторюсь, приведите пример массива который должен получиться в итоге?

Comment: arr[] = {+8,00  -9,10  +09,20  +10,00  +10,20 +10,30  -10,35  -11,00  -11,30  -16,00} условно так(это уже после сортировки по времени). Потом пройтись и счётчиком, за + увеличивать за - уменьшать, максимальное значение счётчика должно быть ответом. Если я правильно рассуждаю

Comment: Обновил ответ, в итоге формируется ArrayList arr, не сортированный. Далее сортируйте и  проходите по нему вашим счётчиком.

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  [arr.add("-"+parts[1]);] из-за этой строки.

Comment: Предполагаю что ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException вываливается на массив parts, скорее всего из-за того что не удалось распарсить строку. Возможно в файле есть строки отличающиеся от приведённых выше, либо пустые строки. Нужно добавить проверку.